# Web Service to get XML from client in C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I want to get an XML response from Client by using  Web service.For this i am going to create a web service that can take XML , so that they can use the web service to send the XML to me.

Remember in this i have to create both ends.

Somebody please advise on this...

```
     public XmlDocument GetXmlDocument(string pXML)
     {
        // Create an XmlDocument object.
        XmlDocument xmlDocumentObject = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocumentObject.LoadXml(pXML);

        // Return the created XmlDocument object.
        return (xmlDocumentObject);
    }
```

The above code will take take any XML as string . How could my client will use this method on there end and send the response to me.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking for at the moment. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and ask a *specific* question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Every time my client create new Job posting, it creates an XML response, then I want to use fields from the XML at my end. So the challenge I'm facing is to create a web service that can take XML from Client .

Comment: No, we need a specific *technical* question. How far have you got, where are you stuck?

Comment: i have added above code which i am using . Any advise...

Comment: @JonSkeet : can you advise now please

Comment: Not really. You've still given us no indication of whether you've set up a web service at all, or what *problem* you've run into. Have you done any web service work before? There really isn't a concrete technical question for us to answer yet.

Comment: @JonSkeet i already created a web service and i got all my answers , i was confused at one point , but now its clear ..